# How do I remove drywall stuck between flooring and wall?

Tags: drywall

[image: Stuck drywall]

I removed some drywall from a wall, but I am having difficulty removing the bottom half an inch because the flooring is about half an inch tall or so, leaving a strip of drywall at the bottom of the wall held in with nails. Is there a fast way to remove this?

Comment: Why does it need to be removed? Could you not just cut it flush with a utility knife, leaving the bottom bit where it is, then nail or screw the new drywall to the bottom plate just above the old drywall and wood molding? Alternatively, couldn't you just remove the wood molding if you want a thorough removal job?

Comment: I think you're right, probably just cutting it flush would be sufficient. I have an electric multitool which should do the job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep it simple, use brute force.

I would just use a wide chisel and hammer to smash it up, then a large screwdriver or some such tool to scrape it out. Diagonal cutter or needlenose pliers would make short work of any nails encountered. Use a shop vac to then clean that slot.

Answer (score 0):

The hammer and chisel idea is a good one. That guy  knows what he's talking about. But before you remove that 1/2" of drywall, consider two things. First why did you want to remove it in the first place over cutting it flush? You might have had the thought that if you have 8' from floor to cieling you would have to cut 1/2" off every board you install to compensate for the old drywall. So consider it again. If this was the case it is better to remove the old. It will make the new installation go faster and smoother. If your 8' is from finished floor(different than floor) you will have a little bit more space to work with also more space to compensate for. If your cieling is exactly 8' in some areas and slightly less in other areas in the parimeter you might be cutting a little off every piece anyway in witch case leave it or you'll be cutting drywall both before and during your installation. The other thing to consider is is this a single story location or the bottom level of a 2 or more story structure? If it is on the second story or higher level this may be part of a fire rated system in which case make sure you put dry wall back in those hard to reach or even seemingly useless areas. A fire rated application only works if its rating is maintained all the way throughout the application. A 2 hr fire rating can be compromised severely if a penetration in the drywall is not finished properly  or even skipping scews in some places. A clue here is if the wallboard you removed had a rating stamp on the back orbread Type X it is fire rated drywall. If it was sound rated make sure to replace with it's equivalent or you might be looking at a job that needs to be redone but just isn't quite worth it to the diy-er because that was not an easy job to do once let alone twice.